# Regular expression to get number between two square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I need to get a string inside 2 pair of square brackets in javascript using regular expressions.

here is my string `[[12]],23,asd`

So far what I tried is using this pattern '`\[\[[\d]+\]\]`'

and I need to get the value **12** using regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the digits using groups

```
"[12]],23,asd".match(/\[\[(\d+)\]\]/)[1]
=> "12"
```

Comment: TypeError: "[12]],23,asd".match(...) is null

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex,

```
\[\[(\d+)\]\]
```

This will extract `12` from `[[12]],23,asd`

It uses [capture groups concept](http://regexone.com/lesson/11)

Comment: sorry I update the question I need to get the value in side the square brackets..

Comment: In addition, how can I check my string in javascript??

Answer (score 1):

```
\[\[(\d+)\]\]
```

Try this.Grab the capture or group 1.See demo.

```
var re = /\[\[(\d+)\]\]/gs;
var str = '[[12]],23,asd';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex you can use, capture groups to get `$1` and `$2` which will be 12 and 43 respectively

```
\[\[(\d+)\]\]\S+\[\[(\d+)\]\]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get 12 you can just use what you mentioned with a capturing group `\[\[(\d+)\]\]`

```
var myRegexp= /\[\[(\d+)\]\]/;
var myString='[[12]],23,asd';
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]); // will have 12
```

Comment: sorry I update the question I need to get the value in side the square brackets..

Comment: `[\d]`? why did you add the brackets there?

Comment: @Cerbrus Sorry it was a mistake ..they are redundant

Answer (score 0):

I've only done it with 2 regExps, haven't found the way to do it with one:

```
var matches = '[[12]],23,asd'.match(/\[{2}(\d+)\]{2}/ig),
    intStr = matches[0].match(/\d+/ig);

console.log(intStr);
```